# split large xlsx to multiple csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to generate multiple csv file by splitting single large xls file using pandas, but only generates a single small file, rest files are not getting generated. Please find the below sample function.

```
def xls_split_to_csv(sourceFilePath):
curr_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
curr_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S")
try:
    logMessage("--------------------------------------------------------")
    logMessage(f'######### Split engine started - {curr_date}  ##########')
    logMessage("--------------------------------------------------------")
    chunk_size = config_params['split_size']
    batch = 0
    df = pd.read_excel(sourceFilePath)
    o_filename = f'file_{curr_date}_{curr_time}_{batch + 1}.csv'
    file_count = math.ceil(len(df) / chunk_size)
    for chunk in np.array_split(df, file_count):
        logMessage(f'Splitting file ----> ({batch + 1} of {file_count})')
        output_path = os.path.join('../TruncatedFile', o_filename)
        chunk.to_csv(output_path, index=False, header=True)
        batch += 1

except ZeroDivisionError as zeroEx:
    logError("Exception: ")
except Exception as ex:
    logError("Exception: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line

```
o_filename = f'file_{curr_date}_{curr_time}_{batch + 1}.csv'
```

into your `for` loop; at the moment you never change the output file name.

Comment: oh yes, didn't notice that the file name is not getting updated. thank you